# Discord.py How to edit emoji settings?

Tags: discord.py

How can I edit emojis settings like require_colons etc.?

I'm unable to use edit to do so. I searched in the API reference but nothing

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time [require_colons](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji.require_colons) will be false is when it's an emoji added by an integration. For instance linking a partnered twitch account to a server allows your twitch subscribers to use your emotes throughout Discord without Nitro and without colons, the same way you do on Twitch. Every element of the emojis that you can edit is stated in [the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Emoji.edit).